# Downloading From Torrent With PHP Script

Tags: php, bittorrent

I'm a php programmer, i want writing a program  that when i give to it a `.torrent` file, automatic download file on my host, anyone can help to me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't program this in PHP, [as it's already been done](http://sourceforge.net/projects/torrentflux/), but what you really seem to what is [µTorrent's WebUI](http://www.utorrent.com/) where you can upload .torrent files to your home computer to download while you are away. (I do this from my Chrome Notebook while I am at work, so it works no matter how obsucure your platform is.)

Comment: No problem, feel free to click the green check mark next to this answer.